How to have multiple scopes with Azure B2G and FastAPI?
So I'm doing my internship period at this company and they've asked me to research Azure B2C and how to integrate it with their FastAPIs. I have this small test API to make a demo. I've been using fastapi-azure-auth and following their documentation here. It's fairly easy. I have a class that gets all the required values from an .env
from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl, ConfigDict, computed_field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class AzureSettings(BaseSettings):
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: list[str | AnyHttpUrl] = ['http://localhost:8000']
    TENANT_NAME: str = ""
    APP_CLIENT_ID: str = ""
    OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID: str = ""
    AUTH_POLICY_NAME: str = ""
    SCOPE: str = ""

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPE_NAME(self) -> str:
        return f'https://{self.TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/{self.APP_CLIENT_ID}/{self.SCOPE}'

    @computed_field
    @property
    def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
        return {
            self.SCOPE_NAME: self.SCOPE
        }

    @computed_field
    @property
    def OPENID_CONFIG_URL(self) -> str:
        return f'YOUR_URL_HERE"'

    @computed_field
    @property
    def OPENAPI_AUTHORIZATION_URL(self) -> str:
        return f'YOUR_URL_HERE"'

    @computed_field
    @property
    def OPENAPI_TOKEN_URL(self) -> str:
        return f'YOUR_URL_HERE'


    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        ConfigDict(extra='allow'),
        env_file='.env',
        env_file_encoding='utf-8',
        case_sensitive=True, 
    )
    
azure_premium = AzureSettings(SCOPE="premium")
azure_admin = AzureSettings(SCOPE="admin")
azure_basica = AzureSettings(SCOPE="basica")


It's pretty much their vanilla provided code, I only modified it so you can create objects with different scopes.
But then, when I use it on my routes, only the last scope created shows on FastAPI and for the life of me I can't figure it out.
This is my main:


description = """
![API Logo](https://mexicocity.cdmx.gob.mx/wp-content/themes/travel-cdmx/src/images/axolotl.svg)
<br></br>
FastApi for learning and testing. API.
"""

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address)

app = FastAPI(
    title="Learning and testing. API",
    description=description,
    contact={'email': 'martin@something.in'},
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/oauth2-redirect',
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'clientId': azure_basica.OPENAPI_CLIENT_ID,
    }
)


app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# Protege /docs y /redoc con api_key
expected_api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")

# Middleware para verificar la API key en las rutas /docs y /redoc
@app.middleware("http")
async def check_api_key(request: Request, call_next):
    if request.url.path in ["/docs", "/redoc"]:
        api_key = request.query_params.get("api_key")

        if api_key != expected_api_key:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=401, content={"detail": "API Key inválida"})

    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

# Database creation
'''
If Mockup is true, uses a SQLite file, otherwise local PostgreSQL instance.
'''
create_db_and_tables()
db = next(get_session_context())
#create_defaultAdmin_user(db)
#create_defaultClient_user(db)

mockup = True

if mockup:
    from database.db_initdata_mockup import insert_libros, insert_pelicula_serie
    insert_libros(db)
    insert_pelicula_serie(db)    
    
# Basic exception handling
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# General exception handling
@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def exception_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    logger.exception(f"Unexpected error: {exc}")
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=500,
        content={
            "message": f"Unexpected Error: {exc.__class__.__name__}.",
            "description": str(exc)
        }
    )

# HTTP exception handling
@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=exc.status_code,
        content={"message": exc.detail}
    )

azure_scheme_scope_basic = B2CMultiTenantAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=azure_basica.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    openid_config_url=azure_basica.OPENID_CONFIG_URL,
    openapi_authorization_url=azure_basica.OPENAPI_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
    openapi_token_url=azure_basica.OPENAPI_TOKEN_URL,
    scopes=azure_basica.SCOPES,
    validate_iss=False,
)

azure_scheme_scope_premium = B2CMultiTenantAuthorizationCodeBearer(
    app_client_id=azure_premium.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    openid_config_url=azure_premium.OPENID_CONFIG_URL,
    openapi_authorization_url=azure_premium.OPENAPI_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
    openapi_token_url=azure_premium.OPENAPI_TOKEN_URL,
    scopes=azure_premium.SCOPES,
    validate_iss=False,
)


@app.on_event('startup')
async def load_config() -> None:
    """
    Load OpenID config on startup.
    """
    await azure_scheme_scope_basic.openid_config.load_config()
    await azure_scheme_scope_premium.openid_config.load_config()


app.include_router(libros_router, dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme_scope_basic)])
app.include_router(peliculasSeries_router, dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme_scope_premium)])
app.include_router(librosPeliculasCombinados_router)
app.include_router(usuarios_router)



This is how it appears at /docs when clicking at the upper right global authentication.
Only one scope
When I go to the single endpoint authentication, the scope doesn't even appear.
No scope appears
The Azure B2C configuration is working correctly, as I can authenticate from the global authentication just fine. It's just that only the last scope appears.
Moving scope requirements to the route files themselves (same result), moving SCOPE creation to object inizialization (same result)

I have more or less solved it. B2CMultiTenantAuthorizationCodeBearer is a static class so it of course overrides everytime. Also Scopes need to be passed as a Dict. It looks something like this.
@computed_field
@property
def SCOPE_NAME(self) -> str:
    return f'https://{self.TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/{self.APP_CLIENT_ID}'

@computed_field
@property
def SCOPES(self) -> dict:
    return {
         f'{self.SCOPE_NAME}/admin': "Acceso a todos los endpoint", f'{self.SCOPE_NAME}/premium': "Acceso a los endpoint premium",     f'{self.SCOPE_NAME}/basica': "Acceso básico", 
    }

I still have some minor problems overall but I'm confident I'll solve them.
